# dynamically increment the number of textboxes according to the number of rows in DB

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, textbox

I am working on a project in which I need to dynamically add textboxes into the jsp page.The number of the textboxes will be equal to the number of rows in the DB table.This could be different for different users.How can I do this using Java Servlets?

Comment: Are you using any framework ?

Comment: No..now just using servlets..@BalwantChauhan

Comment: @user3548232 i think its time to use JSP with your servlets. try fetching your results(from DB) in to any collection at servlet, set it to request or session, using requestdispatcher forward the request and response to a JSP where you iterate throuh the collection and create text boxes (or any html component) depending on the number of entities in the supplied collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are trying to populate the textbox in servlet class, here is the sample code that dynamically populates the textboxe(s).

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    out = response.getWriter();
    response.setContentType("text/html");


    // JDBC driver name and database URL
       final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
       final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://hostname:port/test";

       //  Database credentials
       final String USER = "username";
       final String PASS = "password";


       java.sql.Connection conn = null;
       java.sql.Statement stmt = null;

          //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
          try {
            Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);


          //STEP 3: Open a connection
          System.out.println("Connecting to a selected database...");

            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);

          System.out.println("Connected database successfully...");

          //STEP 4: Execute a query
          System.out.println("Creating statement...");

            stmt =conn.createStatement();


          String sql = "SELECT name FROM table1";
          ResultSet rs = null;

            rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

          //STEP 5: Extract data from result set

            while(rs.next()){
                 //Retrieve by column name

                 String name = rs.getString("name");

                 //Display values
                 System.out.print("Name: " + name);
                 out.println("<input type=\"text\" name=\"last_name\" value = "+name+">"+"</input>");
              }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


}
```

you can paste the code inside the doGet() or doPost() mehtod based on your request type(GET or POST).

If you are using jsp to populate textbox, then there is other way to do it.

Cheers :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*) will give you number of rows
```

Use preparedStatement/Statement.
inside the

```
while(resultSet.next())
{
your html codes for creating textboxes//

}
```

Comment: Thnanks.. I also needed to set the data coming from DB into those textboxes @JqueryLearner

Comment: @user3548232 that is another question.